# Canvas drawing using mouse coords issue?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm drawing to the canvas using the x/y coords of the mouse, but the line that I'm drawing always draws off a little bit, try drawing on here: http://zachrip.net/widgets/onlineedit/index.html (top left) for an example of what I mean. There is no offset so I do not account for it, so I don't know what the issue is?

Comment: I had it working earlier, I don't know what I changed o.O

Comment: Instead of setting the width and height of your canvas in CSS, do it in edit.js; `c.width = 200;` and `c.height = 200;`.

Comment: Here's a working fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/umswe/2/.

Comment: @Rikonator Thank you very much, if you answer the question, I'll choose it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are setting the Canvas **Element Size** through your CSS, but you do not set the **Drawing Surface Size**.

The default size of the Drawing Surface is 300px by 150px. Since you do not set it, but set the Element Size, **the browser scales the drawing surface size to fit the element**. The x and y co-ordinates you get through the mouse event correspond to the Element Size, and not the actual Drawing Surface Size. Which is why you get the offset.

Now, the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umswe/2/)** that I posted earlier merely had you set the size of Drawing Surface, instead of the Element. And that works, but if you'd rather have different Element and Drawing Surface sizes, then you can also do

```
function scaleCoords(x, y) {
    x = x * DrawingSurfaceSize.width/ElementSize.width;
    y = y * DrawingSurfaceSize.height/ElementSize.height;

    return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

**[Example for second method](http://jsfiddle.net/efHJ5/)**.