# Inconsistent Canvas Event Listener making use offsetTop

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, offset, addeventlistener

I have an event listener for a HTML5 web game which is a quiz, but I am having difficulty getting the event listener to get the actual coordinates that should be expected.

Using the javascript console, I found that the coordinate it gets is often wrong.

**EDIT:** I think I know why the problem is occurring, but do not know how to fix it.  I am using a canvas with a long y axis, and have to scroll down to answer some questions. When I scroll is when the coordinates start going wrong. Is there a way to deal with this?

This is my event listener. Please help me fix this problem.

```
canvas.addEventListener('click',ProcessClick,false);
function ProcessClick(ev) {
    my=ev.y-canvas.offsetTop;
    if(ev.y == undefined){
        my = ev.pageY - canvas.offsetTop; 
        }
```

Example of how I use the coordinates-

```
if(eventstate == 'texta6get'){
            console.log(my);
            if(my>300 && my<390){GetAnswer(1);console.log("Answer1 clicked:");}
            if(my>400 && my<490){GetAnswer(2);console.log("Answer2 clicked:");}
            if(my>500 && my<590){GetAnswer(3);console.log("Answer3 clicked:");}
            if(my>600 && my<690){GetAnswer(4);console.log("Answer4 clicked:");}
            if(my>700 && my<790){GetAnswer(5);console.log("Answer5 clicked:");}
            if(my>800 && my<890){GetAnswer(6);console.log("Answer6 clicked:");}
            }
```

Comment: I've had the same issues, set the width and height of the canvas in js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174412/canvas-drawing-using-mouse-coords-issue

Comment: Hi Zachrip, I tried your tip and I set the width and height in javascript and deleted references to it in the CSS. It fixed the problem with the minus numbers at the top. Thanks for your help.

However there is still a problem from before. As I go down the canvas, sometimes it resets the coordinates, for example, I click where I expect the coordinate to be 300, and it is, I click a little lower where I expect 326, and get 15. I have no idea what could cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, the code below gives consistent results.

```
// set up a handler for mousedown events
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});


// get the position of the canvas on the page since it doesn't change
var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;


// handle mousedown events
function handleMouseDown(e){
    mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    // Put your mousedown stuff here
    if(my>300 && my<390){GetAnswer(1);console.log("Answer1 clicked:");}
    if(my>400 && my<490){GetAnswer(2);console.log("Answer2 clicked:");}
    if(my>500 && my<590){GetAnswer(3);console.log("Answer3 clicked:");}
    if(my>600 && my<690){GetAnswer(4);console.log("Answer4 clicked:");}
    if(my>700 && my<790){GetAnswer(5);console.log("Answer5 clicked:");}
    if(my>800 && my<890){GetAnswer(6);console.log("Answer6 clicked:");}
}
```

Comment: I got your code working. It responds alot better than my code, so thank you very much.

Unfortunatly it didn't solve the problem. However I think I know what may be causing it. The problem is I am using a canvas with a long y axis, and have to scroll down to answer some questions. When I scroll is when the coordinates start going wrong. Is there anyway your solution can be modifed to deal with this issue?

Comment: I see...then you'll want to also account for the vertical scroll like this: my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY+$("#canvas").scrollTop());